# Timber - Group ACF fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

At the moment all the ACF fields attached to a post get attached to the `TimberPost` object without any grouping. I'd like to be able to separate them based on what Field Group they belong to. That way I could create cleaner templates in Twig. 
I.e.:

Let `b` be the name of the Field Group which has two fields `field1` and `field2`

Instead of current solution:
`{{ post.b_field1}}` and `{{ post.b_field2}}`

Can we do this:
`{{ post.b.field1}}` and `{{ post.b.field2}}`

I know I can get the fields for specific field group using `acf_get_fields($field_group_id)` but the result is an array instead of a Timber object. Is there a way to feed those fields into a `TimberPost` object?

Answer (score 0):

SpuriouslyAwake: Try extending `TimberPost` with your own class, it'd look something like...

```
class MyPost extends TimberPost {

    function field_group($field_group_id) {
        return acf_get_fields($field_group_id);
    }
}
```

In theory, this would let you do something like.. `{{ post.field_group('b').field1 }}` (in theory, that's untested code, but you get the gist)